# Python Word frequencies

Tags: python

Write a program that reads a list of words. Then, the program outputs those words and their frequencies.

Ex: If the input is:

```
hey hi Mark hi mark
```

the output is:

```
hey 1
hi 2
Mark 1
hi 2
mark 1
```

Here's what I tried:

```
list = 'hey hi Mark hi mark'
text = list.split()

for word in text:
        freq = text.count(word) 
        print(*text, freq)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is your expected output? What you have here is correct, even if words like "hi" are repeated.

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  We expect you to research the topic before you post here -- and to give a complete problem description.

Answer (score 3):

you just need to replace

```
print(*text, freq)
```

to

```
print(word, freq)
```

You want to print just the word, not the full text

The output is going to be

```
hey 1
hi 2
Mark 1
hi 2
mark 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Counter` class is useful for stuff like this:

```
>>> sentence = 'hey hi Mark hi mark'
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> print(Counter(sentence.split()))
Counter({'hi': 2, 'hey': 1, 'Mark': 1, 'mark': 1})
```

or:

```
>>> for word in sentence.split():
...     print(f"{word} {Counter(sentence.split())[word]}")
...
hey 1
hi 2
Mark 1
hi 2
mark 1
```